# UnknownFormatException in Hebrew

Tags: android, locale, translation, hebrew

I've an app that's translated in Hebrew, Spanish, English, Catalan and Hungarian.
All languages work great except Hebrew.

The code shows a lint error on this line:
`lblUsername.setText(getString(R.string.welcome, mUserModel.getUserName()));`

The translation is the following:
strings.xml for English
`<string name="welcome">Welcome, %s</string>`

strings.xml for Hebrew
`<string name="welcome">"ברוך/ה הבא/ה, s%\"</string>`

When I run the app with an English locale set on my device, it runs fine. Same for the other languages. But in Hebrew I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {be.iminds.mresist/be.iminds.mresist.activities.MainActivity}: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                    Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: 
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:2321)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.advance(Formatter.java:2315)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseConversionType(Formatter.java:2394)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseArgumentIndexAndFlags(Formatter.java:2365)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseFormatToken(Formatter.java:2298)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1071)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
                                                                       at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
                                                                       at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1554)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:430)
                                                                       at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:425)
                                                                       at be.iminds.mresist.activities.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:187)
  ...
```

Why would this work for other languages but not Hebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` in the translation string should appear before the `s` and not after it. I'm also not sure why you added the backslash.

Replace

```
<string name="welcome">"ברוך/ה הבא/ה, s%\"</string>
```

With

```
<string name="welcome">"ברוך/ה הבא/ה, %s"</string>
```

Comment: That's it indeed. Weirdly, that doesn't seem to be the case for `%d`.